# how can I get the attribute of Alloy.Models.room_module in titanium

Tags: model-view-controller, titanium, titanium-alloy

this is my code :

```
room_module = Alloy.Models.room_module
console.info "=========room_module======="
console.info room_module
console.info "=========room_module.get room_1======="
console.info room_module.get "room_1"
console.info "=========room_module.room_1======="
console.info room_module.room_1
```

and this is console output :

```
[iphone, 8.2, 192.168.1.126] =========room_module=======
[INFO] [iphone, 8.2, 192.168.1.126] {
    "room_1": "客餐厅",
    "room_2": "卧室",
    "room_3": "厨房",
    "room_4": "room",
    "room_5": "room",
    "room_6": "room"
}
[INFO] [iphone, 8.2, 192.168.1.126] =========room_module.get room_1=======
[INFO] [iphone, 8.2, 192.168.1.126] 客餐厅
[INFO] [iphone, 8.2, 192.168.1.126] =========room_module.room_1=======
[INFO] [iphone, 8.2, 192.168.1.126]
```

why room_module.room_1 can't get the value ? and I wanna show room_module.room_1 to my xml file. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, Alloy Models inherit from Backbone's. When you make a call to Model.get function, this is [what's happening](https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy/blob/master/Alloy/lib/alloy/backbone/1.1.2/backbone.js#L289-L292):

```
// Get the value of an attribute.
    get: function(attr) {
      return this.attributes[attr];
    },
```

When you call console.info(Model), it might be executing [Model.toJSON](https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy/blob/master/Alloy/lib/alloy/backbone/1.1.2/backbone.js#L278-L281) (It doesn't have a toString method):

```
// Return a copy of the model's `attributes` object.
    toJSON: function(options) {
      return _.clone(this.attributes);
    },
```

I see two possibilities:

1. `room_module.attributes['room_1']`
2. `room_module.toJSON().room_1`

In [Alloy docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_XML_Markup-section-35621528_AlloyXMLMarkup-ModelElement) states nothing about accessing your model inside the xml file. You will need to access it from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

backbone js use an attribute object to store the properties. in your case you need to do roommodule.get('room1'). to be consistent it is always a good practicw to use get and set instead of directly access through roommodule.attributes.room1.

because it might trigger some events inside the model.